# type 'Async<string []>' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

Tags: asynchronous, f#, seq

I have a `mySources` variable, `seq<Async <string []>>`. My aim is to flatten the sequence and join all elements in a sequence, in a single `Async<string []>`

I am using `Seq.collect` method.

`let myJoinedAsyncs =  Seq.collect (fun elems -> elems) mySources`

But this line gives me an error on mySource indicating that:

the type 'Async' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Async.Parallel` to collect the inner values and concat the resulting sequences:

```
let flattenAsync (asyncs : seq<Async<'a []>>) = async {
    let! ss = Async.Parallel asyncs
    return Array.concat ss
}
```